# Error Handling java program

Tags: java

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Asterisks
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        try
        {
            File dataFile = new File("Asterisks.txt"); \\ this file says "S 3"
            Scanner in = new Scanner(dataFile);
            String shapeType = in.next(); 
            int Dim = in.nextInt(); 

            if (shapeType.equals("S"))
            {
                for(int loop = 0; loop < 4; loop ++)
                {
                    for (int line = 0; line < Dim; line ++)
                    {
                        for(int elt = 0; elt < Dim; elt ++)
                        {
                            System.out.println(" *");
                        }
                        System.out.println(" ");
                    }                                            
                 }                                                   
            }        
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Data file not found.");
        }    
    }
}
```

(first time putting it on here so please write on the comments what i can do to make it better)
So this is my file and what I don't get is that why this program does not run.

this file has to print out

```
      * * *
      * * *
      * * *
```

the output im getting right now is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at Asterisks.main(Asterisks.java:15)
```

Thank for your help in advance.

Comment: Please also post the output you are currently getting.

Comment: What do you mean, "this program does not run"?  Is there a compiler error message?  A runtime `Exception` stack trace?  Wrong output?

Comment: Yo do not step through the file, so, that is the first error. You do not put anything into the file, so, obviously you cannt see anythign in the file.

Comment: there was no output and i dont know what stack trace is sorry and there wasnt any compiler error message

Comment: what do you mean i am not putting anything into the file? i have Asterisks.txt and in it i have "S 3"

Comment: @Mr.Stack The stack trace is what you edited in (the "Exception in thread..."), and it is also your output in this case. You are all good.

Comment: I'm sorry but I am not getting what you are saying. So are you meaning that my output is ("Exception in thread...") so that my datafile is wrong?

Comment: Either your datafile is wrong, or there is something subtly wrong with how you are reading in its contents.

Comment: I'm fairly sure your datafile is wrong, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works on my machine, so I can only conclude that your version of the Asterix.txt file is bad. Make sure it is correct, and try referencing it with the full path to make sure you're using the correct one. e.g. `new File("C:\\Temp\\asterix.txt");`

Also a few points:

1. The line `for (int loop = 0; loop < 4; loop++)` should be removed to achieve the output you listed.
2. You should close your scanner object.
3. Don't start your variable names with a capital (Dim should be dim).

Comment: how do i reference the full path?

Comment: There is an example in the answer for windows based systems. And check that your text file really is just "S 3", because when I run it with that it works.

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is that `Scanner.nextInt()` is not finding an integer when it reads the file, so it is throwing an `InputMismatchException`.

Comment: So how should I remake the Scanner? should i make it just "Scanner.in;"? Or what else should I be doing?

Comment: @Mr.Stack No, the Scanner is fine. You just have to figure out why it is not finding an integer when it reads the file. I recommend doing a `System.out.println()` on the `Scanner.next()` and seeing what that shows.